# Optional for showAndWait

Tags: javafx, option-type

My question is when the showAndWait's output is null? Because in my program it has two ok and cancel buttons and neither of the cancel and close buttons gives null output.

```
 dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(buttonType -> {
        System.out.println(buttonType);
}
```

when I press the close button(X) and the cancel button the output is(not null):

```
ButtonType [text=Cancel, buttonData=CANCEL_CLOSE]
```

Comment: hmm .. might be a doc error - [mcve] please demonstrating that the last bullet in the java doc description isn't working as specified (which you then can use in a bug report :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Dialog#showAndWait()` returns an `Optional` and will never return `null`. However, the returned `Optional` may be empty. From reading through [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), this will occur in the following cases:

- The [result converter](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#resultConverterProperty) returns `null`.
- There is *only one **non-cancel** button* and the dialog is closed "abnormally" (e.g. the <kbd>X</kbd> button is clicked).

  - But note this will give you an empty `Optional` only if the result converter returns `null` (or there's no result converter) *and* the [result](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#resultProperty) property contains `null`.

Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var btn = new Button("Show dialog...");
    btn.setOnAction(
        e -> {
          Dialog<Object> dialog = new Dialog<>();
          dialog.setContentText("Empty Optional test.");
          dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
          dialog
              .showAndWait()
              .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println, () -> System.out.println("NO RESULT"));
        });
    var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 600, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Running the above, showing the dialog, and then clicking the <kbd>X</kbd> button will result in the following output:

```
NO RESULT
```

In other words, the `Optional` was empty.

---

You mention your tests include cancel buttons. That's why you see a non-empty `Optional`, because by default the result will be the first matching cancel button when the dialog is closed "abnormally". See the "Dialog Closing Rules" section of `Dialog`'s Javadoc for more information.